# How to get a radio button excluyent in a repeater element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, radio-group

I have a repeater using for getting an image nad a radio button on the bottom. I want to achieve a combination of this radio button (repeater speaking) with the property of autoexcluyent feature. How can I achieve it?

As far as I got ...

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%#GetRutaImagen(Eval("id").ToString())%>" />

            <span>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb1" Text='<%#Eval("description").ToString()%>' GroupName="nameGroup"/>
            </span> 

        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>                                                     
</asp:Repeater>
```

With this code I am getting a one radio button per each image but no one autoexcuyent even I am using GroupName property

USING NET FRAMEWORK 4.6.2.

Comment: I think you should make a property for GroupName to your model and bind it to RadioButton with EVAL

Comment: Thanks @SiavashGhanbari but it doesnt work

Comment: You meant to say, all radio button can be checked. GroupName does not apply right?

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya Indeed...

Comment: Ok. Previously, I had tried this but didn't find any proper solution so i used alternate way to manage this such as i called autopostback event on radio button click and unchecked all radio button through code  `foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpTravellerProfiles.Items)
        {
            (item.FindControl("rdoSetAsMasterRecord") as RadioButton).Checked = false;
        }`

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya But I need that current one keep checked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching between SOF and a few forums I implemented a quite right solution using JS. **I am handling another problem related with OnCheckedChanged´s event on RadioButton...**
But the initial issue is fixed.

[Forum Solution](https://forums.asp.net/t/947378.aspx?radiobutton%20inside%20repeater)

I am posting the solution that works for me, using as base as a help coming from a forum, hoping it helps others as well with this bug.

**REPEATER**.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%#GetRutaImagen(Eval("id").ToString())%>" />

            <span>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb1" Text='<%#Eval("description").ToString()%>' GroupName="nameGroup" OnCheckedChanged="rb1_CheckedChanged"/>
            </span> 

        </div>
     </ItemTemplate>                                                     
</asp:Repeater>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    function SetUniqueRadioButton(nameregex, current) {
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {

            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i]

            if (elm.type == 'radio') {

                elm.checked = false;
            }
        }
        current.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

**BACKEND**

```
protected void repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            RadioButton rbLogoSeleccionado = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rb1");
            string script = "SetUniqueRadioButton('repeater1.*nameGroup',this)";

            rbLogoSeleccionado.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PIPEvo.Log.Log.RegistrarError(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if easy way to manage this situation however you can manage by below code. It will be good to wrap your contents into update panel so you can prevent page refresh on checkbox changed.

Additionally, **IsChecked** property being used to initialize checked on page load. You can remove if not required.

**.ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <span>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rb1" Checked='<%# Eval("IsChecked") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rb1_CheckedChanged" Text='<%#Eval("description").ToString()%>' />
            </span>
         </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<test1> lst = new List<test1>();
        lst.Add(new test1() { Id = 1, description = "R1", IsChecked = false });
        lst.Add(new test1() { Id = 3, description = "R2", IsChecked = true });
        lst.Add(new test1() { Id = 2, description = "R3", IsChecked = false });
        lst.Add(new test1() { Id = 4, description = "R4", IsChecked = false });

        repeater1.DataSource = lst;
        repeater1.DataBind();
    }
 }


protected void rb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
    {
        (item.FindControl("rb1") as RadioButton).Checked = false;
    }
    (sender as RadioButton).Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for you efford @JitendraRangpariya. I will rate it as it deserve it. Well I am researching and I am checking solutions based in jquery an JS ideas. As far as I get it, I will post it for helping others. Your solution is working but it manages the situation from the backend.... In any case it works as I desire it... Thanks mate (if you believe the question deserve it, do you mind to rate it as well? Thanks again)